# Trying to display mapview on a window kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to display a mapview on my naviwindow. However, i dont really know how to implement the `class MapviewApp` to the naviwindow. Any help would be appreciated since im new to kivy !!

.py file

```
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

KV = """

WindowManager:
    NaviWindow:

<NaviWindow>:
    Label:
        text:"hi"
"""
class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        map = MapView(zoom=18, lat=1.3099, lon=103.7775, double_tap_zoom = True)
        marker_1 = MapMarker(lat=1.3099, lon=103.7775)
        map.add_marker(marker_1)
        return map


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class NaviWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. What *exactly* do you want to do but can't?

Comment: i want to display the map from mapview into my naviwindow

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask